# Cast parent class to child class in Java

Tags: java, java-8

I have 2 classes. One for API request and one for response. My job is to add 2 params `error, result` to the request body and send it back in the response.

I tried casting but it fails :

```
for (InteracReportingDetails item : interacReportingDetailsList) {  
            result1.add((InteracReportingDetailsResponse) item);
}
```

What is an easy/correct way of doing this ? Is there a way to avoid calling individual setters ?

Should I go for interface ? Cloning ?

---

1st class - Request body for API (Spring):

```
public class InteracReportingDetails {
    
    private String interacReportingCode,interacReportingTypeCode,participantId, interacReferenceId, interacReferenceIdType, reportedByCode, transactionTimeStamp, interacReportingTimeStamp, memo;
    public String getParticipantId() {
        return participantId;
    }

    public void setParticipantId(String participantId) {
        this.participantId = participantId;
    }

    
    public String getInteracReportingCode() {
        return interacReportingCode;
    }

    public void setInteracReportingCode(String interacReportingCode) {
        this.interacReportingCode = interacReportingCode;
    }

    public String getInteracReportingTypeCode() {
        return interacReportingTypeCode;
    }

    public void setInteracReportingTypeCode(String interacReportingTypeCode) {
        this.interacReportingTypeCode = interacReportingTypeCode;
    }

    public String getInteracReferenceId() {
        return interacReferenceId;
    }

    public void setInteracReferenceId(String interacReferenceId) {
        this.interacReferenceId = interacReferenceId;
    }

    public String getInteracReferenceIdType() {
        return interacReferenceIdType;
    }

    public void setInteracReferenceIdType(String interacReferenceIdType) {
        this.interacReferenceIdType = interacReferenceIdType;
    }

    public String getReportedByCode() {
        return reportedByCode;
    }

    public void setReportedByCode(String reportedByCode) {
        this.reportedByCode = reportedByCode;
    }

    public String getTransactionTimeStamp() {
        return transactionTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setTransactionTimeStamp(String transactionTimeStamp) {
        this.transactionTimeStamp = transactionTimeStamp;
    }

    public String getMemo() {
        return memo;
    }

    public void setMemo(String memo) {
        this.memo = memo;
    }

    public String getInteracReportingTimeStamp() {
        return interacReportingTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setInteracReportingTimeStamp(String interacReportingTimeStamp) {
        this.interacReportingTimeStamp = interacReportingTimeStamp;
    }
}
```

2nd Class :

```
public class InteracReportingDetailsResponse extends InteracReportingDetails {
    
    private String error, result;
    
    
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using :

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);
```